# android, is there something like "while key down"?

Tags: android

I want my clickable ImageView to change its image while it is being pressed and return back to its original image when it is no longer being pressed. What do you think might be the best way for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (and the way used across the Android framework) is to use state list drawables. This lets you define a single drawable that can change based on states of the view. The one you're looking for is the pressed state. If you supply a state list with a pressed state you will get this behavior without writing any extra code.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 1):

You could use the view's [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) API.  Make sure that nothing is taking the focus away from the view or it won't get called though.